# How to add class, id, placeholder attributes to a field in django model forms

Tags: django, forms, attributes, django-forms, form-fields

I have a django model like below

**models.py**

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 300)
    description = models.TextField(max_length = 2000)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

**forms.py**

```
class ProductForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        exclude = ('updated', 'created')
```

**product_form.py**(just an example)

```
 <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{% url 'add_a_product' %}" method="post">
         <div id="name">
           {{form.name}}
         </div> 
         <div id="description">
           {{form.description}}
         </div> 
   </form>
```

Actually I want to display/render the html output like below

```
<input id="common_id_for_inputfields" type="text" placeholder="Name" class="input-calss_name" name="Name">

<input id="common_id_for_inputfields" type="text" placeholder="Description" class="input-calss_name" name="description">
```

So finally how to add attributes(id, placeholder, class)to the model form fields in the above code ?

Comment: See documentation for [django.forms.Widget.attrs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.Widget.attrs). This is implemented in the [attributes template](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.1.x/django/forms/templates/django/forms/widgets/attrs.html).

Comment: One thing is avoid using same ids in different inputs..

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
#forms.py
class ProductForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        exclude = ('updated', 'created')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProductForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['description'].widget = TextInput(attrs={
            'id': 'myCustomId',
            'class': 'myCustomClass',
            'name': 'myCustomName',
            'placeholder': 'myCustomPlaceholder'})
```

Comment: This worked well for me, except that it erased all options from my Select widget. I found out that you can skip the widget declaration all together and still set its attributes like so:

`self.fields['description'].widget.attrs={
            'id': 'myCustomId',
            'class': 'myCustomClass',
            'name': 'myCustomName',
            'placeholder': 'myCustomPlaceholder'}`

Also seems a bit cleaner for me.

Comment: If you want to add bootstrap classes to all forms without having to override constructor each time see my answer below.

Comment: Is there also a way to give the same id as the name?

Answer (score 33):

Field ids should be generated automatically by django, to override other fields:

```
class ProductForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        exclude = ('updated', 'created')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProductForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['name'].widget.attrs\
            .update({
                'placeholder': 'Name',
                'class': 'input-calss_name'
            })
```

Comment: Are id's really SHOULD be generated automatically? You can override the id as well.

Comment: You can override id as well (just like I showed you, you can override any attribute), but I think it's better to use django generated ids, unless you don't have any control over them (like when you use 3rd party js libraries or smth..)

Answer (score 27):

I really like Dmitriy Sintsov's answer but it doesn't work. Here's a version that does work:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    for field in iter(self.fields):
        self.fields[field].widget.attrs.update({
            'class': 'form-control'
    })
```

## update

add this condition for better

```
if self.fields[field].widget.__class__.__name__ in ('AdminTextInputWidget' , 'Textarea' , 'NumberInput' , 'AdminURLFieldWidget', 'Select'): 
     self.fields[field].widget.attrs.update({ 'class': 'form-control' })
```

Comment: This is much better than having to form the entire Widget each time. I created a class BasicForm which extends forms.ModelForm that does this. I just extend BasicForm instead of model form and automatically get bootstrap classes on all forms. I went a step further and append the classes to any custom css classes which may already be there. See my answer for code example.

Answer (score 21):

You can update forms.py as below

```
class ProductForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        exclude = ('updated', 'created')
        widgets={
                   "name":forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Name','name':'Name','id':'common_id_for_imputfields','class':'input-class_name'}),
                   "description":forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'description','name':'description','id':'common_id_for_imputfields','class':'input-class_name'}),
                }
```

Answer (score 7):

Slightly modified version of excellent mariodev answer, adding bootstrap class to all form fields, so I do not have to re-create form input widgets for each field manually (short Python 3.x super()):

```
class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in self.fields:
            self.fields[field].widget.attrs.update({
                'class': 'form-control'
            })
```

Comment: It also works if you use "self.fields" insted of "self.Meta.fields".

Answer (score 3):

Adding to answer from Derick Hayes I created a class BasicForm which extends forms.ModelForm that adds the bootstrap classes to every form that extends it.

For my forms I just extend BasicForm instead of model form and automatically get bootstrap classes on all forms. I went a step further and append the classes to any custom css classes which may already be there.

```
class BaseModelForm(forms.ModelForm):

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(BaseModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    # add common css classes to all widgets
    for field in iter(self.fields):
        #get current classes from Meta
        classes = self.fields[field].widget.attrs.get("class")
        if classes is not None:
            classes += " form-control"
        else:
            classes = "form-control"
        self.fields[field].widget.attrs.update({
            'class': classes
        })
```

Answer (score 3):

**add_class** filter for adding a CSS class to form field:

```
 {% load widget_tweaks %}     
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{% url 'add_a_product' %}" method="post">
                 <div id="name">
                   {{form.name|add_class:"input-calss_name"}}
                 </div> 
                 <div id="description">
                   {{form.description|add_class:"input-calss_name"}}
                 </div> 
           </form>
```

[django-widget-tweaks library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-widget-tweaks)

Comment: If you don't want to have to override the default forms, this is the way to go! I've been using it on Django projects for years. `{% render_field field class+="form-check-input" %}`

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

```
class ProductForm(ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(label='name ', 
            widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'name '}))
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but if someone is still looking to add custom class to all of his form fields, then you can use this one liner

```
class ProductForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        exclude = ('updated', 'created')
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ProductForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    custom_attrs = {
        'class': 'form-control',
        'toggle-data': 'mydiv',
    }
    # adds our custom_attrs to each element of the form 
    [self.fields[i].widget.attrs.update(custom_attrs) for i in self.fields]
```