# Django - Assign default value to field in ModelForm

Tags: python, django

In my application I have a `CreateView` that must initialize some fields of the model with a default value, different from the default defined inside the model.

I do not want the user to edit the value, thus I put the field in the `exclude` list

```
class AForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = AModel
        exclude = ['a_field']

class AView(CreateView):
    form_class = AForm
```

The question is: where do I set the value of `a_field`?

I tried to define `clean` methods inside `AForm`, like thus

```
class AForm(ModelForm):
    [...]
    def clean(self):
        d = super(AForm, self).clean()
        d['a_field'] = 10
        return d
```

however `a_field` is set to whatever its default value defined in the model is, rather than `10`. I also tried defining `clean_a_field`, but that is simply not executed.

If I remove `a_field` from the `exclude` list, then the `clean` and `clean_a_field` will work, but the form won't validate unless I render some `<input name="a_field">` inside the template, which is not optimal.

Comment: Did you define `clean_a_field` or just `clean`?

Comment: I tried both. They are both ignored.

Comment: Really? The form's clean method should always be called. An alternative is to override the form's save method.

Comment: Tried removing the fields from exclude, making them hidden(or not required and not displaying in the front end), then setting the default value in the clean method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue in a way that makes me satisfied, although I'm still not 100% happy with the code.

`a_field` is a required (by the model) field, thus it is necessary to render an `<input name="a_field">` inside the template. The trick was to make `a_field` non-required:

```
class AForm(ModelForm):
    a_field = Field(required=False, 
                    widget=forms.HiddenInput)
    class Meta:
        model = AModel

    def clean_a_field(self):
        return 10
```

This way I can avoid rendering the field in my template, and the form will still validate. And even if the form is rendered with `{{ form.as_p }}`, `widget=forms.HiddenInput` saves my day.

Comment: where did you import Field from?

Comment: `django.forms.Field`

Answer (score 4):

Exclude the field from the form, then in the view you can set the value before you save the form:

```
form = AForm(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    new_record = form.save(commit=False)
    new_record.a_field = 10
    new_record.save()
```

You also might want to avoid the `exclude` list and specify which fields you'd like to include with the `fields` attr of the form definition. See the first paragraph [here in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#selecting-the-fields-to-use).

Comment: This is a nice idea, but in my opinion it does not blend cleanly with CreateView. The form is saved by `CreateView.form_valid()`; overwriting this method without calling `super` doesn't look very future proof to me.

Answer (score 0):

You set a default value in the model. From the official [document](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#default),
a_field = models.CharField(max_length=7, default=''), for example

Comment: This does not prevent the user from modifying the value.

Comment: Are you using modelForm to do this? If then, you need to add attribute disabled = "disabled" in the input field.  Google yielded this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19489699/how-to-add-class-id-placeholder-attributes-to-a-field-in-django-model-forms

Comment: Yes, I am using `ModelForm`. Disabling the field in HTML does not prevent the user from editing it if she really wants to (or if she has an old browser not recognizing the `disabled` attribute).

Besides the field is still going to show in the form, which is not what I want: I want to choose the value for the user. Using `HiddenIntput` does not help either: the user can still edit if he wants to. Combining with `clean` or `clean_a_field` would work, but is against DRY, and I can't believe there is no simpler way.

Comment: Gotcha ! choosing the value for the user is backend stuff. For front-end, can't you render the value of that field as text so it is uneditable?

Comment: Not very different from using a `hidden` field, and not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

I have a way to Face this situation. Follow the following process:

1. **Remove** 'a_field' from the **excludes** in AForm.
2. **Do not expose** 'a_field' in HTML template. i.e. Don't give the user option to change the value via Form in Template. This would ensure that normal user's wont modify the value.
3. To prevent completely, **over-ride** `get_form_kwargs` in the View. 
   This would provide or over-ride your desired value to 'a_field' and save that

e.g.

> ```
> class AView(CreateView):
>     form_class = AForm
>
>     def get_form_kwargs(self):
>         kwargs = super(AView, self).get_form_kwargs()
>         if self.request.method in {'POST', 'PUT'}:
>             # Change post data to over-ride or provide value of 'a_field'
>             data = self.request.POST.copy()
>             data.update({
>                 'a_field': 'value'
>             })
>             kwargs['data'] = data
>         return kwargs
> ```